# Restlet client not allowing to define custom 'Authorization' header

Tags: http, https, http-headers, restlet, restlet-2.0

I need to put following rest request using restlet client:

```
GET
https://www.xyz.com/resource/blah/
Authorization: Bearer XToken
```

I am able to get the XToken in a separate call, but in the presented call i am unable to set the 'Authorization' header in my ClientResource object.

Can somebody suggest me what code needs to be added for the following line of code that i have:

```
clientResource.setChallengeResponse(new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.XXXX, bearerToken)
```

Creating and adding 'Authorization' header in restlet is giving me errors from restlet client library.

thanks in advance

Ashish Sharma

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Restlet client library ver. 2.0.X is still very counter intuitive and lacks documentation.

So dumped it and started using [HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/) HttpClient ver. 4.2.2, it was a breeze as compared to restlet client library, it's way much better than restlet client.

Comment: To create a new ChallengeScheme in Restlet, just do: new ChallengeScheme("Bearer", "Bearer"), bearerValue)

Comment: I've been trying to make this work with restlet for hours now.  It's a bit of a nightmare.  Still getting Challenge scheme HTTP_Bearer not supported by the Restlet engine. in 2.2-M6